# How is georeferencing information stored in geo-refrenced 3d models?

Tags: qgis, 3d-model, opendronemap, unity3d

I have a .obj file downloaded from Open Drone Map, labelled as geo-referenced model. How can I figure out the geo-referencing information stored in it? I need to use it in unity or any other such software.

Comment: This Python library look like it can return OBJ vertex data.  https://pypi.org/project/PyWavefront/